# How to make EditText like this using only Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I want to create exactly the same `EditText` but I had a problem with icons because I can't configure central vertical position of drawableLeft. Can I achive this without `drawableLeft` and using only properties of `TextInputEditText`?

Example:

[image]

Comment: you can add drawablePadding to achieve this.

Comment: drawablePadding change gap between text and drawable